# MariaDB JOIN syntax

Tags: sql, join, mariadb, left-join, inner-join

I'm trying select some records from three linked tables (many to many relationship) and then `left join` the results with another table. I get the following error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'u.id' in 'on clause'
```

here is the full example of the query that raises that error:

```
drop database if exists example1;
create database example1;
use example1;
create table users (id integer not null auto_increment primary key, name varchar(50));
insert into users (name) values ('Alice'),('Bob'),('Carol');

create table roles (id integer not null auto_increment primary key, role varchar(50));
insert into roles (role) values ('developer'),('hr'),('sales');

create table users_roles (user_id integer, role_id integer);
insert into users_roles (user_id, role_id) values (1,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,2);

create table activity (id integer not null auto_increment primary key, user_id integer not null, description varchar (200));
insert into activity (user_id, description) values (1, 'logged in'), (1, 'logged out'), (2, 'changed password');

SELECT u.name AS 'Username',
       a.description AS 'Activity',
       r.role AS 'Role'

FROM users u, users_roles ur, roles r

LEFT JOIN activity a ON a.user_id = u.id

WHERE ur.role_id = r.id AND ur.user_id = u.id;
```

After several tests, I've come to the conclusion that the problem is listing more than one table in the `FROM` clause and then following it with a `LEFT JOIN`. So I suppose I should write this instead:

```
[...]
SELECT u.name AS 'Username',
       a.description AS 'Activity',
       r.role AS 'Role'

FROM users u 
 JOIN users_roles ur ON ur.user_id = u.id
 JOIN roles r ON r.id = ur.role_id

LEFT JOIN activity a ON a.user_id = u.id
```

And in fact this does work as expected. My question is: what's wrong with the first version of my `SELECT`? Shouldn't that be supported by the MySQL syntax and, if not, why not?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: This is a faq. Googling your error message your problem will be among the answers.  If you chopped your code down to minimal in preparing a MRE you would have `select * from u , a join r` still returning what you don't expect & you could google re comma plus join. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Comma means cross join but with lower precedence than keyword JOINs. So the JOIN ON is done first & the left table of the comma is not known there. So don't mix comma with keyword joins. PS You have a syntax error. Read the grammar & manual. Show that constituent subexpressions are OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix implicit and explicit joins! Bad things happen when you do that, because different types of joins have different precedence rules: explicit joins are evaluated first, which causes the error you are getting. At the time when the `left join` is interpreted, aliases defined in the implicit joins have not been seen yet.

Matter of fact, use explicit, standard joins consistently, in all your queries: implicit joins are legacy syntax, that should not be used in new code.

```
SELECT u.name AS Username,
       a.description AS Activity,
       r.role AS Role
FROM users u
INNER JOIN users_roles ur ON ur.user_id = u.id
INNER JOIN roles r ON r.id = ur.role_id
LEFT JOIN activity a ON a.user_id = u.id
```